# Proof Big Theta (sum of a geometric)

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Here sum of a geometric, where c is a positive real number.

$g(n)=1+c+c^2+...+c^n$

$\theta(1)$ if $c<1$

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is known that
$$
1 \leq g(n) < \sum_{m=0}^\infty c^m = \frac{1}{1-c}.
$$
You take it from here.